# What property type for uploaded files, when designing a model class in ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, model

I have a form on an ASP.NET MVC site, it will upload a couple of files. I'm trying to mimic the default project's "AccountModel" or "LoginModel" examples, to build DataAnnotation based server and client side validation (unobtrusive jQuery plugin based client side validation, new in MVC 3.0).

For example:

```
public string FirstName
public string LastName
public string Email
public ?? Photo
public ?? File
```

Each of those properties matches the name/id of a form field on the page. When submitted, ASP.NET MVC should map those fields to the properties.

What do I set the Photo/File properties to so they are mapped by MVC and can be validated with DataAnnotations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `HttpPostedFileBase`

Comment: I'll give it a shot (I'm not at my dev box right now). Hopefully by using that type ASP.NET MVC will take the posted form and associate the data with the model property. Thanks!